# How to publish an Android library from my private GitHub repository without sharing source code?

Tags: android, aar

I am working on a custom Android library. I have created a working library module for testing and now I want to publish it so that I can use it in upcoming projects.

I researched regarding this and found options such as **JitPack**, **MavenCentral**, **JCentral**, **GitHub Packages** and also one that I found interesting was **creating a public GitHub repository of your AAR files and Maven metadata** and implementing it using `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER_NAME/REPO_NAME`. I found this one interesting because as per my knowledge (from research) GitHub Packages requires access token with read package permissions.

What I tried was publishing my test library module to Nexus local and then accessing it. It's working fine but I want it to be live 24/7.

Now, what I want is to get more detail on publishing/uploading AAR files directly to public GitHub repository and also I found it interesting but my mind is keep saying me that this is a temporary solution so I also want a permanent solution.

My `AGP` is `v7.2.2` and `gradle` is `v7.3.3`

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this problem ? I'm also in a similar situation.